# Better approach to link a enum class with a constant class

Tags: java, design-patterns, constants

I have one Country enum which has all the countries defined as an enum. I would like to link the region class i.e. RegionAfghanistan with the AFGHANISTAN constant enum in Country class. I have defined a hashmap in RegionAfghanistan which has all the region constants for Afghanistan. Like this, I can have RegionUSA, RegionAustralia, etc and these all are linked to Country enum.

I have an approach as shown below when I call from the main method I get all the regionalist for Afghanistan. I am not sure it is the right way, I would like to know if there is any better approach for doing this. Since this uses hashmap and everything, I am not sure if this is the right thing to do. Can you suggest a better approach, Since I want to link the enum class with another region classes?

```
public interface Region {

    public Map<String, Regi> getRegionList();
}

public interface RegionMethod {

    public String get3166_2Code();
    public CountryCategory getRegionCategory();
}

public class Regi implements RegionMethod {
    
    private String sub3166Code;
    private CountryCategory regionCat;
    
    Regi (String sub3166Code, CountryCategory regionCat){
        this.sub3166Code = sub3166Code;
        this.regionCat = regionCat;
    }

    @Override
    public String get3166_2Code() {
        return sub3166Code;
    }

    @Override
    public CountryCategory getRegionCategory() {
        return this.regionCat;
    }

}

public class RegionAfghanistan implements Region {

    private static final Map<String, Regi> REGION_LIST = new HashMap<String, Regi>();
    
    static {
        
        REGION_LIST.put("Badakhshān", new Regi ("AF-BDS*", CountryCategory.PROVINCE));
        REGION_LIST.put("Baghlān", new Regi ("AF-BGL*", CountryCategory.PROVINCE));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Regi> getRegionList() {
    
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(RegionAfghanistan.REGION_LIST);
    }
}

public enum Country {
    
    AFGHANISTAN("Afghanistan","AF","AFG",004, new RegionAfghanistan());
    ........
}

public class MainTemp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Country.AFGHANISTAN.getRegion().getRegionList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Countries and Regions change over time, so they are not something you should hardcode in code. They are better stored in a database that can be updated live, or in resource files that are easier to maintain.

Comment: I understand since this is ISO standard, So we will not change much, Hence we have to do this in code. Could you please suggest how we can do this efficiently in code.

Comment: [Quote](https://www.iso.org/iso-3166-country-codes.html): *"ISO 3166 (Country Codes) is **regularly updated** to reflect changes in country names and subdivisions. These changes are done by the ISO 3166 Maintenance Agency (ISO 3166/MA)."* --- Just because it's a standard, doesn't mean it is immutable. As I already said, ***countries change over time***. I don't know how often. but having to update source code, rebuild the application, and reinstall it wherever it is installed, does not seem like the best approach.

Comment: @Andreas That depends _very much_ on the specific type of application. Server applications are abandoning infrastructure such as XML externalized config precisely because in practice modifying code-based configuration and redeploying is just as cheap.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to approach your goal is using the configuration file such as xml, csv.
Ex:

- Define a country csv file which will store all the countries code, countries name.
- Define Afghanistan_region, USA_region... csv file which store all the regions of each country.
- Based on the country code you can find out the region of this country.
- To optimize the performance, you can cache the country list, region list. However, in case you have changed the content in the csv, you need clear cache to make sure the application can use the latest change.

With this way, it's easy/save time to maintain/modify because all the value now is move on the configuration file.